# Number of connected-components in a undirected graph

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, graph

I'm going over some graph algorithms (**this is not homework; I'm just brushing up on algorithms and data-structures**) and I have a question. Assume I have the following undirected graph:

```
var graph = {
    9: [19, 26],
    13: [19, 5],
    17: [],
    26: [11, 18],
    18: [9],
    19: [],
    23: [24],
    24: [],
    11: [],
    18: []
};
```

The graph basically looks like this:

[image]

How many connected-components are in this graph? From just looking at the graph, it looks like there are 3 components. But if I actually implement the algorithm (iterating over each vertex, and doing a bfs using that vertex as a starting point *if* that vertex is undiscovered. Also, the bfs will mark any vertex it encounters, as discovered).

If I start with `9`, I end up discovering the following nodes: `[19, 26, 11, 18]`. However, `13` is not discovered because it is not in `19`'s adjacency list. However, `19` is in `13`'s adjacency list.  This is why I end up with one extra component.

Is this correct? Are there actually 4 separate-components and if so, is my understanding of connected-components wrong?

Comment: I wonder what merited a downvote on this question... it's quite legitimate.

Comment: the graph isn't particularly well suited for other problems

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that for adjacency list representations of **undirected** graphs, you have to either

(1) use symmetric adjacency lists, i.e. when putting in a new edge `ab`, add `b` to `adjlist[a]` **and** vice versa

or

(2) traverse all vertices' adjacency lists everytim e you're looking for the existence of an edge.

Since (2) is horribly inefficient, you'd usually go with (1). This is also the convention for adj lists used in general. If I were presented with your adj list, I'd assume the graph was directed.

Answer (score 3):

You can change your adjacency list representation, your representation is 'directed' but your picture is undirected. For edge(a,b) graph {a: [b], b:[a]}